# How to use TFTP to transfer file at startup automatically in linux?

Tags: linux, boot, tftp

I am trying to get a file through tftp on boot-up. Tftp server has been properly setup on another machine. I am running tftp get in a shell script like this:

```
tftp 192.1x.x.110 << !
get file.txt
quit
!
```

This shell script runs fine when I execute it, and I am able to get the file. I am trying to run it as a systemd service, but when it runs at boot-up it just gives me an empty file.

This is how my systemd service looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Grabbing TFTP file
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/debian/./test-tftp.sh
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=tftp_file.service
```

My systemd service also works fine when I start it myself and I get the file with data inside it, but only at boot up its giving me an empty file. So I am thinking maybe I am not starting the service at the right time in the boot process.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Does the tftp tool output any error messages when started as a service on boot?

Comment: @grawity No errors. I even tried running service type as "oneshot", and that also didn't change anything.

Comment: Type=oneshot is more suitable. Does it output anything if you remove StandardOutput=?

Comment: @grawity After removing StandardOutput, I can see this error "tftp: sendto: Network is unreachable". Why is network unreachable even if I have After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target in there.